# How to merge values with similar keys for NSdictionary

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

Hello i have situation where i have getting a raw response for the server like this

```
(
    {
        "Nov 2018" =         {
            AudioFileURL = "https://www.GeorgeA.m4a";
            AudioFileText = "GeorgeA";
        };
    },

    {
        "Nov 2018" =         {
            AudioFileURL = "https://www.GeorgeB.m4a";
            AudioFileText = "Georgeb";
        };
    },
    {
        "Nov 2018" =         {
            AudioFileURL = "https://www.Georgec.m4a";
            AudioFileText = "Georgec";
        };
    },
    {
        "Sep 2018" =         {
            AudioFileURL = "https://www.GeorgeB.m4a";
            AudioFileText = "GeorgeD";


        };
    }
)
```

now i would like to combine all the Values with the same key so that i can use them in section with UITableView controller . can someone please provide me some guidance for that .

The output i am looking for is something like this

```
(
{
        "Nov 2018" = {        
            [AudioFileURL = "https://www.GeorgeA.m4a";
            AudioFileText = "GeorgeA"],

            [AudioFileURL = "https://www.GeorgeB.m4a";
            AudioFileText = "GeorgeB"],

            [AudioFileURL = "https://www.GeorgeC.m4a";
            AudioFileText = "GeorgeC"];

        };
    },
{
        "Sep 2018" =         {
            [AudioFileURL = "https://www.GeorgeB.m4a";
            AudioFileText = "GeorgeD";]


        };
}
)
```

Comment: Create struct holding url and text field and make dictionary into key = String and value = array of new struct

Comment: Can you please provide me an example .

Comment: @Alex Can you share what you have tried till now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make a struct(s) that represents the info you want in one cell:

```
struct AudioFileInfo {
    let urlString: String
    let text: String

    init(dict: [String: String]) {
        urlString = dict["AudioFileURL"] ?? ""
        text = dict["AudioFileText"] ?? ""
    }
}

struct CellInfo {
    let date: String
    let audioFileInfos: [AudioFileInfo]
}
```

Then you can:

```
let cellInfos = response
    .flatMap {
        $0.map { ($0.key, AudioFileInfo(dict: $0.value)) }
    }
    .reduce([CellInfo]()) { partial, item in
        var new = partial
        if let index = partial.index(where: { $0.date == item.0 }) {
            new[index] = CellInfo(date: partial[index].date, audioFileInfos: partial[index].audioFileInfos + [item.1])
        }
        else {
            new.append(CellInfo(date: item.0, audioFileInfos: [item.1]))
        }
        return new
    }
```

This will give you an array of CellInfo objects.

As a general rule, this how you solve this sort of problem. First define a type that represents the output you want, then manipulate the input until you create objects of that type. Playground is your friend for this sort of thing.

Comment: i am getting an error ,Value of type 'Any' has no member 'map' on this line " $0.map { ($0.key, AudioFileInfo(dict: $0.value)) }"

Comment: Cast it to the type you need: `$0.map { ($0.key, AudioFileInfo(dict: $0.value as! [String: String])) }`

Comment: hey can you do me a small favour , can you please tell me how can i access cellinfo, in numberOfRowsInSection and UITableView, cellForRowAt method .

Comment: If you don't know how to do that, then you need to take some basic classes on iOS development.

Comment: Sure i am very new to ios , can you help me now .

Comment: That's not the way this site works. If you have a question, ask the question. This isn't a site for finding a mentor. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work for you

```
typealias AudioFile = (url: String, text: String)

class DictArray {
    var items: [MainModal]

    class MainModal {
        let date: String
        var files: [AudioFile]

        init(key: String, file: AudioFile) {
            self.key = key
            self.files = [file]
        }

    }

    init(dictArray: [[String: [String: String]]]) {
        for dict in dictArray {
            if let date = dict.keys.first {
                if let item = items.first(where: { $0.date == date }) {
                    guard let value = dict.values.first as? [String: String] else { continue }
                    let file = AudioFile(url: value["AudioFileURL"]!, text: value["AudioFileText"]!)
                    item.files.append(file)
                } else {
                    guard let value = dict.values.first as? [String: String] else { continue }
                    let file = AudioFile(url: value["AudioFileURL"]!, text: value["AudioFileText"]!)
                    items.append(MainModal(key: date, files: [file]))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

DictArray(dict: json)
```